# Show category in Previous/Next links

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

[image: next]

In place of the word `PREVIOUS` and `NEXT`, I would like to display the level 2 categories of the respective posts.

This is my current code:

```
function twentyfourteen_post_nav() {
        $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( get_post()->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
        $next     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

        if ( ! $next && ! $previous ) {
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <nav class="navigation post-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <?php
            if ( is_attachment() ) :
                previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">Published In</span>%title', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
                else :
                    previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">Previous Post</span>%title', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
                    next_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">Next Post</span>%title', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
                endif;
                ?>
            </div><!-- .nav-links -->
        </nav><!-- .navigation -->
        <?php
    }
endif;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display the level 2"? it's a child of taxonomy or you want display a term before and after your actual term ?

Comment: It's a child of taxonomy. I have 3 levels of categories: _father, son, grandson_. I would like the category _son_ to be displayed.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the snippet you have that is printing back your current Next/Prev links?? You'll need a combination of `get_next_post()`, `next_post_link()`, and a custom query of that Level 2 cat.

Comment: The question has been updated with the function `twentyfourteen_post_nav()` that I'm using.